# Ошибка преобразования json в объект с помощью moshi

Tags: json, kotlin, moshi

вид json строки:

```
{"server":999,
"photo":"eyJvaWQiOi0yMjUwNjExNzUsInBob3RvIjp7Im1hcmtlcnNfcmVzdGFydGVkIjp0cnVlLCJwaG90byI6IjQ0ZmVmMTc2YTU6eCIsInNpemVzIjpbXSwibGF0aXR1Z",
"mid":853732551,
"hash":"7448f93f405dfd5c444f5d4aabb84942",
"message_code":2,
"profile_aid":-6}
```

Объект создан:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class uploadResult(
    @Json(name = "server")
    val server: Int,
    @Json(name = "photo")
    val photo: String,
    @Json(name = "mid")
    val mid: Int,
    @Json(name = "hash")
    val hash: String,
    @Json(name = "message_code")
    val message_code: Int,
    @Json(name = "profile_aid")
    val profile_aid: Int
)
```

Код преобразования:

```
                           val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
                                .addLast(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()
                            val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<uploadResult> = moshi.adapter(uploadResult::class.java)
                            val result = jsonAdapter.fromJson(response.body!!.toString())
```

На присвоения jsonAdapter выдает такую ошибку:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract boolean isValue()' of interface kotlin.reflect.KClass.
    at com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory.create(KotlinJsonAdapter.kt:269)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:146)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:106)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:80)
    at ru.Frozik6k.VKmon.API.VkClient$createGroup$1$onResponse$4.onResponse(vkService.kt:156)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:161)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```

в файле pom.xml прописано:

```
    <properties>
        <kotlin.version>1.8.21</kotlin.version>
        <tornadofx.version>1.7.20</tornadofx.version>
        <moshi.version>1.15.1</moshi.version>
    </properties>
```

и

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.moshi</groupId>
            <artifactId>moshi</artifactId>
            <version>${moshi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.moshi</groupId>
            <artifactId>moshi-kotlin</artifactId>
            <version>${moshi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```